# Configuring WMS from a MSSQL data source with MapGuide Open Source

Tags: web-mapping, data, spatial-database, sql-server, wms

I've having trouble configuring WMS out of MapGuide Open Source. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Installed MapGuide
2. Downloaded MapGuide Maestro
3. Created a "feature" in Maestro that connects to MSSQL2008
4. Added the "feature" to a new layer
5. Added the new layer to a new map
6. Combined those three things into a "package", imported that into Site Administrator.

Thus, MapGuide has access to the data, and WMS in enabled. Yet, doing a `GetCapabilities` request returns a 404 out of my browser and a result but no information about the data from the MapGuide UI.

**How do I "point" the WMS service to my MSSQL data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem, as `GetCapabilities` now reflects my data.

The only change that I made was to **right click my *Layer* in MapGuide Maestro and click *Properties*. In the *WMS* tab**, I entered some details for the title and selected the checkbox that was named something like *Available* or *Enabled*. That did the trick!